# Sentence: use of is/are with you yourself

Tags: pronouns

Can't seem to figure this one out:

> Of course, it is more difficult to analyze those signs if you yourself **is/are** stressed beyond belief.

Both seem to sound wrong (or maybe I'm overworking). Removing *yourself* solves it; yet I'd like to still keep the emphasis. As far as I'm concerned, the double pronoun is perfectly fine to use, and also is present in different languages: German "Sie selbst"; Russian "вы сами"; Latvian "jūs paši"; etc.

Comment: I choose "are".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's ***are***.

*You* goes with *are* and the emphatic *yourself* (or *yourselves* if plural) doesn't change that.

> Of course, it is more difficult to analyze those signs if you yourself are stressed beyond belief.

Comment: +1 I might add a clarification, such as *... you (both singular and plural) goes with are ...*

Answer (score 0):

I think I would propose an alternative: *have been*.

> Of course, it is more difficult to analyze those signs if you yourself have been stressed beyond belief.

Comment: Why? The present seems much more natural and logical than the perfect here …

Answer (score 0):

You can also switch the word order.

> Of course, it is more difficult to analyze those signs if you are yourself stressed beyond belief.
>
> Of course, it is more difficult to analyze those signs if you are stressed beyond belief yourself.